# Add multiple todos (Angular)

Tags: arrays, angular

I'm new to angular, want to create board with name and categories, but have some issues. 
In my page there are 4 inputs, one for `name` and 3 for `categories`. How can I add categories dynamically? Now I make it like this:

```
<form class="form">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="todo.name" name="name">

    <label>columns</label>
    <input placeholder="To do" [(ngModel)]="todo.columns[0].name" name="colname">
    <input placeholder="Doing" [(ngModel)]="todo.columns[1].name" name="colname1">
    <input placeholder="Done" [(ngModel)]="todo.columns[2].name" name="colname2">

    <button (click)="onSubmit()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Add todo</button>

  </form>
```

board.model.ts

```
export class Columns {
  constructor(
    public id?: string,
    public name?: string) { }
}
export class Board {
  constructor(
    public id?: string,
    public name?: string,
    public columns?: Columns[]
  ) { }
}
```

board.component.ts

```
export class BoardComponent{
  boards: Board[];

  board: Board = {
    name: '',
    columns: [
      {
        name: ''
      },
      {
        name: ''
      },
      {
        name: ''
      },
    ]
  }

  constructor(private boardService: AddBoardService) { }

  onSubmit() {
    this.boardService.addTodo(this.board) //here I send it to firebase
    console.log(this.board)
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add inputs dynamically, or add to the boards array?

Comment: @dallows I want to create a popup where always will be 3 inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using angular reactive forms. Refer the below code :

> If you have any doubts please refer to the stackblitz working example
> [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-fields-6ftabx)

**app.component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="send(userForm.value)">
  <label>Name </label>
  <br>  
  <input type="text" formControlName="name">
  <br>
  <br>  
  <div *ngFor="let column of getcolumnsFormControls(); let i = index">
    <label>columns {{i}} </label>    
    <input [formControl]="column" type="text">
  <button (click)="removecolumn(i)">Remove columns</button>    
  </div>
  <br>  
  <button (click)="addcolumn()">Add new columns</button>
  <br>
  <br>  
  <input type="submit">
</form>
  <br>  

{{userForm.value | json}}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  userForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [],
      columns: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control(null)
      ])
    })
  }

  addcolumn(): void {
    (this.userForm.get('columns') as FormArray).push(
      this.fb.control(null)
    );
  }

  removecolumn(index) {
    (this.userForm.get('columns') as FormArray).removeAt(index);
  }

  getcolumnsFormControls(): AbstractControl[] {
    return (<FormArray> this.userForm.get('columns')).controls
  }

  send(values) {
    console.log(values);
  }
}
```